# CSS Opacity doesn't generate a color overlay?

Tags: css, colors, overlay, alpha

I'm havin a issue.

I'm trying to recreate this gif in pure CSS:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XivDv.gif

So, here is a sample of the code

http://jsfiddle.net/E4WMh/

```
border-color: rgba(x, x, x, .333); /* Reduce the opacity to 33.3% to overlay others layers. */
```

where the colors doesn't overlay to create a white solid, just the top layer overlay to bottom layers and join the solid color.

So, is possible to overlay colors to obtain the same effect ("Overlay" effect in photoshop)?

Maybe `-webkit-filter` can be useful?

Comment: Yeah, that's not how simple alpha compositing works in CSS. It's the same as if you used the normal blending mode.

Comment: Exacly, I want something like overlay or multiply+ in photoshop.

Answer (score 2):

*Credit to css-tricks.com*

Although I have no experience with CSS 3, I do have little experience with how drawing works on computers.

What you are looking for is a way to change how the blend mode works in css.

I looked up something called "  mix-blend-mode: multiply; "

But you're not going to find a vast amount of support from major browser at the current time.

This is a great article on how it all(will) works: http://css-tricks.com/basics-css-blend-modes/

Comment: Sound great, but http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backgroundblendmode brownser support is kinda unsupported. (Firefox latest stable version is 29.0).

Comment: tested on all the major browsers (with latest versions) and neither of them supports the so-called `background-blend-mode`, that article is something for future (maybe CSS4) and looks like it's much far from reality in near future.

Comment: I do agree with @KingKing.
Currently tested on firefox 30.0 ths script:
`alert(isSupported('backgroundBlendMode'));
alert(isSupported('mixBlendMode'));
function isSupported(property){return property in document.body.style;}`

And return false over 'mixBlendMode', seems to be a next CSS generation to use that property.

Comment: Sorry, it's all I could come up with css related with blend modes.

Comment: @Lemony-Andrew no, it's cool, you got + from me... but this doesn't awnser the question.

Comment: @Lemony-Andrew possibly, but the idea isn't use JScript or Canvas. Pure CSS, anywhay the support is pretty good througt blend in cavnas is supported from Firefox 20.0+.